# remove deprecated fill_parent in Android Studio

Tags: android, designer

After I had to look up a couple of times if **match_parent** or **fill_parent** is the up-to-date value for layout_width in the designer, I wonder if the deprecated fill_parent can be removed from a template or wherever it comes from.

Has someone achieved to do this? I guess that would help many of us unless they work with really old code.

Comment: I also wonder why this is downvoted. There is no other question like this, nor is there a solution somewhere else that could be found using obvious keywords.

Answer (score 1):

There is

`layout.template` file should be modified.

Go to your SDK Path. In my case

`sdk\platforms\android-[version]\templates`

And open `layout.template` in any editor like Notepad++

And modify it according to your need.

Comment: This looks like it only modifies the setting of a linear layout that I can create. I don't see any changes after modifying this btw. I want to tell Android Studio to no longer show this value in all dropdowns that allow to set a width or height.